# I'm the other form

Tags: riddle, rhyme, movies

> The other form, they call me
>   Horror is all they can see
>   I am not a killer bee
>   Yet a queen I serve fiercely
>
> Dark in color, light in steps
>   Silently we close our gaps
>   Next, a thing - your face it wraps
>   A young will be your mishaps
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> an [Alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)), or Xenomorph.

*The other form, they call me*

> "Other form" is almost literally the translation of "xeno morph" from ancient Greek to English.

*Horror is all they can see*

> *Alien* is a horror film.

*I am not a killer bee*
*Yet a queen I serve fiercely*

> The Xenomorphs have [queens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)#Queen) which they serve.

*Dark in color, light in steps*
*Silently we close our gaps*

> They do seem to be dark in colour, and they creep up on their prey stealthily.

*Next, a thing - your face it wraps*

> Facehugger!

*A young will be your mishaps*

> After hugging your face, the xenomorph will plant an embryo (young), or chestburster.

Comment: "Light in steps, silently we close our gaps" probably refers to the stealthy nature of the monster; it closes the gap between itself and you silently. To "close the gap" means "catch up".

Comment: Guess I made it way too easy. Silenus is right about the stealthy thing. Also, "other form" is the literal translation of the classical compound "Xenomorph". I avoided using "alien form", but xeno- also means "other" or "strange".

Comment: @busukxuan Too easy, or you were just unlucky that a [scifi.se] mod was the first person to see it ;-) Nice one re "xenomorph" - I'll edit.